# Oracle homework - I'm stumped

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is the last question for my Oracle homework for the year and I cannot figure out even where to start..must be a bad brain day.

Can someone help me with this?

Using a WITH clause write a SELECT statement to list the job_title of those jobs whose maximum salary is more than half the maximum salary of the entire company. Name your subquery MAX_CALC_SAL. Name the columns in the result JOB_TITLE and JOB_TOTAL, and sort the result on JOB_TOTAL in descending order. 
Hint: Examine the jobs table. You will need to join JOBS and EMPLOYEES to display the job_title.

Thanks!

This is what I have so far...

```
WITH MAX_CALC_SAL  AS (
    SELECT e.salary, SUM(e.salary) AS tot_salary
    FROM   employees e JOIN jobs j
    ON     e.job_id = j.job_title
    GROUP BY j.job_title
),
avg_cost AS (
    SELECT SUM(e.salary)/COUNT(*) AS avg_salary
    FROM   e.employee
)
SELECT * 
FROM   e.employee 
WHERE  avg_salary > (SELECT max_salary / 2 
                     FROM j.jobs)
ORDER BY job_total
```

Comment: Which parts of the question are confusing you?  What have you got so far?

Comment: And more importantly: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
WITH max_calc_sal
  AS (SELECT job_id,
             j.job_title,
             MAX(e.salary) AS job_total
        FROM jobs j
       INNER JOIN employees e
       USING (job_id)
       GROUP BY job_id,
                j.job_title)
SELECT job_title,
       job_total
  FROM max_calc_sal
 WHERE job_total > (0.5 * SELECT MAX(job_total)
                            FROM max_calc_sal)
 ORDER BY job_total DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The names defined with the `WITH` clause is not automatically present in your final query. They work like derived tables, so you have to select from them, or join with them, to get their data.

```
WITH my_with_table AS (SELECT 9 AS X FROM DUAL)
SELECT X FROM my_with_table;
```

Comment: @APC I'm not sure if what I am doing is even on the right track.